# How to check memory utilization in solaris 11 machine?

Tags: bash, awk, solaris, free, vmstat

May I know how to calculate total memory utilization and percent of a Solaris 11.3 machine?

Am I wrong in below calculation? or any other way?

```
memfree=$(vmstat 1 2 | awk '{print $5}' | tail -1)
memtotal=$(vmstat 1 2 | awk '{print $4}' | tail -1)
memused=$((memtotal-memfree))
mempercent=$((memused * 100 / memtotal))
```

OS version is: SunOS 5.11 11.3 sun4v sparc

---

For reference, the [`vmstat(8)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E72487/vmstat-8.html#scrolltoc) output of `vmstat 1 2` on a freshly installed Solaris 11.4 VM looks like this:

```
root@solaris:~# vmstat 1 2
 kthr      memory            page            disk          faults      cpu
 r b w   swap  free  re  mf pi po fr de sr cd -- -- --   in   sy   cs us sy id
 0 0 0 4672456 2127260 342 1628 0 0 0 0  0 48  0  0  0  566 10129 2466 11 13 76
 0 0 0 4753212 830276 5 141  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  527 1205  469  2  5 93
```

Comment: Does that calculation not give you the output you expect? Does it produce error messages? The more information you provide in your question the better chance we'll be able to help you.

Comment: For us that don't regularly use Solaris: What is the output of `vmstat 1 2`?  Add that as reference info to your question please (not in comments).

Comment: @Kusalananda [OP doesn't like to post that](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/116934?m=56333802#56333802), do know why, even asked to replace real data with dummy data but keep the formatting but still no response to that too.

Comment: @αғsнιη OK, I'll set up a Solaris VM and test later...

Comment: As far as I can see, you can not say that the amount of swap space is the same as the total amount of memory in the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Solaris provides a mdb dcmd for this:

```
root@solaris:~# mdb -k
Loading modules: [ unix genunix specfs dtrace mac cpu.generic uppc zvpsm scsi_vhci zfs zvblk ip hook neti arp usba kssl sockfs lofs random idm cpc crypto fcip fctl fcp ufs logindmux ptm nfs ipc ]
> ::memstat
Page Summary                            Pages             Bytes  %Tot
---------------------------- ----------------  ----------------  ----
Kernel                                 368046              1.4G    9%
ZFS                                   2236330              8.5G   53%
Anon                                   955993              3.6G   23%
Exec and libs                           95340            372.4M    2%
Page cache                              32844            128.2M    1%
Free (cachelist)                        61894            241.7M    1%
Free (freelist)                        443246              1.6G   11%
Total                                 4193693             15.9G
```

This can be used in a command like `echo ::memstat|mdb -k` if you just want the output without using the mdb prompt.